# Neo4j-shell returns errors if comments are in the called file

Tags: shell, neo4j

Using neo4j-shell (v2.0.0 M05) I get errors when running script file (-file) with comments (//comment) in it. When I remove the comments, all works fine.

Comment: Please provide an example of the failing code so people can investigate.

Answer (score 1):

How does it fail? 
And what does your file look like?

I think shell comments are starting with a hash `#`, and
Cypher comments start with `//`, you're right that's an inconsistency

I used it with both kind of comments in the past